# Is it possible for me to create a Python bot that scrapes Spotify from a list I give it, and if it finds the correct song, it adds it to a playlist?

Tags: python, web-scraping, spotify

I'm currently creating a very large Spotify playlist, and it's a bit mind numbing finding songs one by one, and adding them to the playlist. Would there be any way to make this easier with the use of Python, and if so, how?

Comment: You might want to look at the spotipy package https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.22.0/

Comment: See the example at https://github.com/spotipy-dev/spotipy/tree/master/examples, in particular https://github.com/spotipy-dev/spotipy/blob/master/examples/add_tracks_to_playlist.py

Answer (score 1):

Sure its possible, Spotify has a REST API and you can use the following endpoints :

[Search for a track](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-search-item/)

[Add tracks to a spotify playlist](https://developer.spotify.com/console/post-playlist-tracks/)

There are a large amounts of examples and packages available for most programming languages here :

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/libraries/